# Pandas Dataframe, aggregate and put the data in the next column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, data-science

I have a dataset like this:

```
Country   Name      Match   Result
US        Martin    Win     3
US        Martin    Lose    1
US        Martin    Draw    5
UK        Luther    Win     5
UK        Luther    Draw    3
```

I'd like to add two more columns with sum result from Win, Lose and Draw, and percentage of each match like this:

```
Country   Name      Match   Result  All Percentage
US        Martin    Win     3       8   0.375
US        Martin    Lose    1       8   0.125
US        Martin    Draw    5       8   0.625
UK        Luther    Win     6       10  0.6
UK        Luther    Draw    4       10  0.4
```

I've already tried using groupby and got result for size total match. However I don't know how to put it in the next column.

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the `All` column for `Martin` be `9`, not `8` (5 + 3 + 1)?

Comment: yes my mistake, it should be (5+1+2) .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), sample `DataFrame` was changed:

```
df['All'] = df.groupby(['Country','Name'])['Result'].transform('sum')
df['Percentage'] = df.Result.div(df.All)
print (df)
  Country    Name Match  Result  All  Percentage
0      US  Martin   Win       2    8       0.250
1      US  Martin  Lose       1    8       0.125
2      US  Martin  Draw       5    8       0.625
3      UK  Luther   Win       6   10       0.600
4      UK  Luther  Draw       4   10       0.400
```